# golang os.Getwd возвращает неверный путь на macos

Tags: golang, macos, path

Для разработки использую мак бук про на м1, при вызове функции os.Getwd() в ide возвращается правильный путь, но когда я делаю билд, то функция начинает возвращать путь к папке текущего пользователя, где бы я не запускал файл билда. Спасите меня.
(на винде все работает как надо)

Comment: "где бы я не запускал файл билда" имею в виду в какой бы папке на маке я не запускал, всегда одинаковый результат

Comment: причем все функции, которые так или иначе должны возвращать путь к текущей папке на маке при запуске билда возвращают путь к папке текущего юзера

Comment: то есть `//Users/username` ?

Comment: @SeniorPomidor да, но вот как оказалось функция os. Executable возвращает всегда правильный путь. Но все же, почему другие функции не работают как надо на маке?

Comment: Сама постановка вопроса неправильная. Никто не обещал, что "WorkingDir" - это папка откуда запущено приложение. Это просто на Виндовс так, но это не значит, что так будет везде. "Но все же, почему другие функции не работают как надо на маке?" - правильно работают, просто соглашение в этой OS другое.

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov почему тогда если я запускаю код из ide на маке то папка правильно определяется?

Comment: Вероятно, IDE по другому конфигурирует запускаемый файл.

Comment: > Вероятно, IDE по другому конфигурирует запускаемый файл.
А терминал, откуда ты запускаешь по-своему

Comment: Если тебе нужна папка, откуда запущено приложение, то надо именно это искать (`os.Executable`), а не пытаться добиться какого-то определённого поведения от вещей, предназначенных для другого (`os.Getwd`)